# Añadir contador a iconos en xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

estoy trabajando en Xamarin y mi consulta es la siguiente. Cuando realizo un tabs necesito que en los iconos de cada tab tengan un contador con esa famosa burbujita roja que como en whats app cada vez que  recibo un mensaje va incrementando. Quisera saber si alguien me puede ayudar de como realizarlo. Saludos

Comment: No conozco mucho de Xamarin pero, ¿ya buscaste en google por Xamarin Badge?

Comment: Hola si encontre algunas maneras de realizarlo con paquetes de Nuggets, pero queria saber si habia alguien experimentado para que me indique la mejor manera de realizarlo. Gracias por comentar un saludo

Comment: Imagino que habras visto este paquete https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge yo para tabs no conozco otra manera.

Comment: si creo que es lo que hay por el momento, me deberé quedar con eso, muchas gracias por ayudar. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente librería:

- https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda